# Qt3D Billboards: how to make plane always face to camera

Tags: camera, rotation, qt3d

I try to use camera's viewVector to make plane face to camera, but it will turn Clockwise or Counterclockwise when Camera rotate to left or right.

Can I make the plane always face to camera without turning Clockwise or Counterclockwise?

[image: begin]

[image: camera left rotation : plane turn Counterclockwise]

[image: camera right rotation : plane turn clockwise]

I think `camera->upVector()` can help me maybe, but I don't how to use.

My code :

```cpp
class planeTransformClass : public Qt3DCore::QTransform {

public:
    planeTransformClass( Qt3DCore::QNode *entity = nullptr ) :Qt3DCore::QTransform(entity) {}

signals:
    void faceTo( QVector3D v ) {
        setRotation(QQuaternion::rotationTo(QVector3D(0,1,0), -v));
    } ;
};
```

```cpp
// Background
        Qt3DCore::QEntity *planeEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(rootEntity);
        Qt3DExtras::QPlaneMesh *planeMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QPlaneMesh(planeEntity);
        planeMesh->setHeight(2);
        planeMesh->setWidth(2);

        Qt3DExtras::QTextureMaterial planeMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QTextureMaterial(planeEntity);
        Qt3DRender::QTexture2D *planeTexture = new Qt3DRender::QTexture2D(planeMaterial);

        FlippedTextureImage *planeTextureImage = new FlippedTextureImage(planeTexture);
        planeTextureImage->setSize(QSize(3000, 3000));
        planeTexture->addTextureImage(planeTextureImage);
        planeMaterial->setTexture(planeTexture);
        planeMaterial->setAlphaBlendingEnabled(true);

        // Transform
        planeTransformClass planeTransform = new planeTransformClass(planeEntity);
        planeTransform->setRotationX(90);
        planeTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(2, 0, 0));

        planeEntity->addComponent(planeMesh);
        planeEntity->addComponent(planeMaterial);
        planeEntity->addComponent(planeTransform);

        // connect camera's viewVectorChanged
        camera->connect( camera, &Qt3DRender::QCamera::viewVectorChanged, 
                 planeTransform, &planeTransformClass::faceTo);
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qt3d-experiments)? There's a billboard example which might be what you're looking for. Although it also changes the size of the plane so I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: YES, that is what I want. I try to clone project and compile c++ and qml. It can work. But I don't know how to convert it to only c++ code and make it be able to work.

Comment: I tried to implement it in C++ but didn't manage to get it to work. I'm really not sure what the issue is. But if it's not absolutely necessary, why don't you just use QML? I once implemented a larger project in C++ only and feel like it would have made my life easier, had I also used QML.

Comment: How do I use QML in Qt3DWindow?  My billboard need to show in it and I don’t have experience in QML. If I use QML , I will need to conform c++ and QML because other module is work in c++.

Comment: Well the link to the project uses QML with Qt3D. You can't use it directly in a Qt3DWindow - this means that you hvae to translate existing C++ Qt3D code to QML but its fairly easy. If you have time to wait I mgiht get round to trying to make the project run over the weekend.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm sorry to bother you all the times. By the way, can I define RootEntity and Camera then pass to qml? If it is workable, can you make an example project to teach me?

Comment: Don't worry it's a bit complicated to understand it all. C++ and QML classes actually have a 1-1 mapping. i.e. behind every QML class, there is a C++ - the actual implementation. Checkout the `main.qml` in the project that I provided in my answer. `Entity` in there stands for `Qt3DCore::QEntity`. The same holds for `Camera` which correspondns to `Qt3DRender::QCamera`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution using geometry shader

There is already a C++ translation [this QML code that I tried to translate](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qt3d-experiments/tree/master/billboards) (using geometry shader):

https://github.com/ismailsunni/qt3d-custom-shader

My own translation can be found [here](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-billboards). It works now after solving the issues mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63079722/qt3d-geometry-shader-working-in-qml-but-not-in-c?noredirect=1#comment111551955_63079722).

---

#### Solution without geometry shader

I got a different version running based on [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53442). You can find my implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-billboards-size-changing/tree/no_instanced_rendering). The billboards don't change their size when the camera moves, i.e. become smaller and larger on screen like every other object, but I hope you can work with that.

On the master branch the images also move for some reason as can be seen in this image:

[image]

The `no_instanced_rendering` branch doesn't use instanced rendering and displays everything correctly.

**Edit**
I'm sorry I'm not using your example but I don't have time anymore to adjust it. Check out the [patch](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qt3d/+/182053) related to the bug report I mentioned. The person implemented a material with this effect, you should be able to extract it and make it run.

Comment: I run it and it shows `"\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x80\xBF\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x80@\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xE0@\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x80@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xA0@\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\xC0@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@@\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\xE0@"
Could not read shader source file: ":/shaders/light.inc.frag"`
 Is my environment wrong?

Comment: It is no show error, but the png is not face to me.  I think I need the environment.
[run result](https://i.imgur.com/nGBCXO2.png)
[in frag file shows red line](https://i.imgur.com/cNgWSpr.png)

Comment: Qt 5.14.1 and Qt 5.11.2 .  But it is no error message. There are comment about cameraPos and cameraUp in vert file. I need to uncomment ?

Comment: I try to change modelViewMatrix and solve it. [Original to comment part in vert File](https://i.imgur.com/M7mRGke.png)   and   [changed part in vert File](https://i.imgur.com/UHnRh9T.png)   then  **[It WORK~~~~](https://imgur.com/a/A2TQXyN)**

Comment: !!!!!!!  I don't notice that **the objects also move a bit** !!!!!!!
It is about the matrix Calculation.  How do I fix it?  (QAQ)

Comment: I fixed it.  I guess that `modelViewMatrix` can't be changed in my environment. **[So I use this to change it](https://i.imgur.com/YieowL5.png)**  **[And it work finally](https://imgur.com/a/VLiyRiu)**  Thanks. Next step, I will try to fix its scale. I hope I would be successful.

Comment: Both of  them can  work.  I just use `mat4 billboardMatrix = modelViewMatrix;` and `billboardMatrix[0][0~3] = modelMatrix[0][0~3];`  and  `billboardMatrix[2][0~3] = modelMatrix[2][0~3];` then `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * billboardMatrix * offsetPos;`

Comment: Original code is `modelViewMatrix[0] = modelMatrix[0];` 、 `modelViewMatrix[2] = modelMatrix[2];` then `gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * offsetPos;` in vert file.  I think they mean the same code.

Comment: @xyLi check out my update answer - there already exists a C++ port of the QML code which is working properly!

Comment: It shows `QOpenGLShader::compile(Fragment): ERROR: 0:? : 'variable' : is removed in Forward Compatible context gl_FragColor`.   Can the freg file be writed like `no_instanced_rendering`'s ?

Comment: Which one? https://github.com/ismailsunni/qt3d-custom-shader this one?

Comment: [no_instanced_rendering/billboards.frag](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-billboards-size-changing/blob/no_instanced_rendering/billboards.frag) This. The error maybe show that I can't use `gl_FragColor`.

Comment: I don't know where this issue comes from but I suggest you use the code that I mentioned in my updated answer: https://github.com/ismailsunni/qt3d-custom-shader. It's a working C++ port of the [QML code](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qt3d-experiments/tree/master/billboards) that I have suggested to you in the first place.

Comment: ohohoh~~~ I  fixed again.  [In your **qt3d-billboards/blob/master/billboards.frag**](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-billboards/blob/master/billboards.frag) **[I show this](https://i.imgur.com/o9ox0En.png)**   and  [It be fixed.](https://i.imgur.com/OzCiMFW.png)

Comment: Yeah well I didn't bother fixing the texture in the shader because it was a showcase for billboarding ;)